# Can more than one app claim a URL in Universal Links / App Links? What happens?

Tags: mobile, android, ios

Can I have more than one application claim the same URL for Universal Links or App Links?

What occurs on the end user device when such a (developer permitted) collision occurs?

- Is the experience the same on Android and iOS?
- Will there be a prompt, allowing the user to pick which app to open the deep link URL in?

Answer (score 5):

No, a collision is not possible.

The way that [app links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html) and [universal links](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) work is

1. Your web page contains a URL to a file **on your web server**
2. The file contains the information that tells the device what app to open.

The link might look like this:
`https://<domain>/apple-app-site-association`

The file might look like this:

```
"applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
        {
            "appID": "9JA89QQLNQ.com.apple.wwdc",
            "paths": [ "/wwdc/news/", "/videos/wwdc/2015/*"]
        },
        {
            "appID": "ABCD1234.com.apple.wwdc",
            "paths": [ "*" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So in order to create an app association using of of these links, you have to own a server that matches the domain in the URL.

You can only put files on web servers that you own, of course; nobody else can (unless you have given them permission or they have hacked you).  So whoever owns the web server also owns the app association.  No collisions.

Comment: So in other words, if I offer a free and paid version of my app, the URL of each app must be different and therefore can't overlap features?

Comment: I want a URL to open whichever app is installed.  Free if that is, paid, if that is.

Comment: The app association can include multiple apps.  If the user has more than one installed, the phone will display a dialog allowing them to choose. In your case I think they would have only the one app (free or paid, not both) so you should be OK.